# List / discover all Azure SQL Database backup retention policies

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-backups

I have a large number of Azure SQL Databases and I would like to create a list or report of some kind that shows what backup retention policies are in place for each one.

All I can find is how to check on per-database or per-server basis.  This would take me a long time and is error-prone and not something I can check on a regular basis or easily provide to an auditor/manager who wants confirmation that everything is being backed up and retained properly.

Is there a way to obtain all this information in one place?  A PowerShell solution would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Powershell` commands to get the Long-term retention policies for your SQL Server or even for each database using below commands:

```
# get all LTR policies within a server
$ltrPolicies = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ServerName $serverName | `
    Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionPolicy

# get the LTR policy of a specific database
$ltrPolicies = Get-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $dbName `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
```

You can also use `CLI` command to get LTR policies for each database.

```
az sql db ltr-policy show \
    --resource-group mygroup \
    --server myserver \
    --name mydb
```

In the above code only you can write the code for each database to get the LTR policies.

Refer: [Manage Azure SQL Database long-term backup retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-backup-retention-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-cli)